# Android: ids.xml versus using @+id/id_name everywhere

Tags: android, xml, refactoring

So I'm trying to decide whether it would be worth it to refactor out my current use of id's in all of my android layouts to an ids.xml file, or to just leave my view code the way it is (with multiple views sharing ids and both views using "@+id/id_name).

Is there a significant compile/runtime performance benefit to refactoring out the ids to the ids.xml file? How about if the application gets bigger?

Related resources:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `<item type="id">` resources in my app because I have `TextEdit` views that serve a similar purpose in more than one `Activity`.

Comment: I see. And then as the project gets larger, we just wind up with a huge ids.xml right, correct? Is there a better way of organizing the IDs other then ids.xml + XML comments like: 

<resources>
<!-- Super AwesomePictureGallery IDs are here -->
    <item type="id" name="picture_border" />
    <item type="id" name="picture" />

... etc etc.

</resource>

?

Comment: @TarryC The name of the XML file is not important. You can put `<item>` tags in any XML file in the `res/values` subfolder of your project. This allows you the freedom of organizing the `id`s in whatever manner is appropriate for your project.

Answer (score 1):

ids.xml has the following advantage: all ids were declared, so compiler can recognize them. If something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBelow="@id/text2"
    android:text="...."/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="...."/>
```

Can result in compiling error because text2 was refered before declared

Comment: I can see the compiler time catch of bad ids, although I was wondering if there were standard practices as to how to organize ids for android components in layouts. If I were to put "@+id/" in front of every ID I reference I wouldn't get the error you described above.